# How to get Data from a registry key value via command line

Tags: command-line, command, registry, registrykey

I am trying to get the Data from a registry key value via command line

I can retrieve the value of a registry key using the following code

```
reg query HKCU\Software\[PATH_TO_MY_DIR] /v [KEY_NAME]
```

This works as expected and outputs three items:

- Name
- Type
- Data

I am trying to get the data from the value in command line how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done very simply using a `FOR` loop along-side it's `Token` System. Since `reg query` will output the variables in a `one two three` format, we can use `tokens=3` to grab only the third item in the output.

**From CMD:**

```
for /F "tokens=3" %A in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\[PATH_TO_MY_DIR]" /v "[KEY_NAME]"') DO (Echo %A)
```

**From BATCH:**

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\[PATH_TO_MY_DIR]" /v "[KEY_NAME]"') DO (Echo %%A)
```

Comment: This won't work if the registry value contains spaces.

Comment: changing token to =3,* and adding %B in echo will take care of spaces for the last field. But you will have to change(add) the token if there is space in the keyname.

Comment: Also, `reg query` outputs a blank line followed by a header listing the key path before the 'value/type/data' line. If this header contains 2 (or more) spaces (probably in the [PATH_TO_MY_DIR] or that with a subkey name) then it will produce spurious output. So should be `for /f "skip=2 tokens=...` (note: even though a blank line is ignored when tokenizing, it must be included in the skip count)

Comment: It's worked for me with spaces, thanks Zunair. : for /F "tokens=3*" %A in ('reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam" /v "SteamExe"') DO (Echo %A %B)

Comment: using `FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('reg query ...') DO echo %%~B`
If registry value is a string then `%%A` will have `REG_SZ` and the remainder will be pure in `%%B`